# Count how many times class member was printed

Tags: c++, class

I need to count how many times class members were printed using function `Print` which is **inspector**. Constructor should set private elements of class.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
class Vector3d {
  double x, y, z;
  mutable int count = 0;
  public:
    Vector3d();
  Vector3d(double x, double y, double z);
  void Print() const;
  int GetCount() const;
};
Vector3d::Vector3d() {
  count = 0;
}
Vector3d::Vector3d(double x, double y, double z) {
  count = 0;
  Vector3d::x = x;
  Vector3d::y = y;
  Vector3d::z = z;
}
void Vector3d::Print() const {
  count++;
  std::cout << "{" << x << "," << y << "," << z << "}";
}
int Vector3d::GetCount() const {
  return count;
}
int main() {
  Vector3d v1(1, 2, 3);
  v1.Print();v1.Print();v1.Print();
  Vector3d v2(v1);
  v2.Print();v2.Print();
  std::cout << v2.GetCount();
  return 0;
}
```

I used `mutable` int to enable changing element of const function. For `v1.GetCount()` I get output 3, which is correct. However, for `v2.GetCount()` I get output 5, which is wrong (correct is 2).

Could you help me to fix this? Where am I making mistake?

Comment: What should be printed instead of 5 for `v2.GetCount()`?

Comment: `v1.GetCount()` is correct, for `v2.GetCount()` it should print 2

Comment: `void ResetCount() { count = 0; }` and then `Vector3d v2(v1);` followed by `v2.ResetCount();`.  That way the copy-ctor can make a fidelity copy and that copy can be independently reset when/if desired.

Comment: Or a delegating constructor, `Vector3d::Vector3d(Vector3d const& v, int new_count) : Vector3d(v) { count = new_count; }`  Note that count has to be re-assigned in the body of the constructor.  Then `Vector3d v2(v1, 0);`.

Comment: @Eljay here's the autotest I get wrong https://ibb.co/nkNhpYv I cannot change function declarations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to overload copy constructor and copy assign operator for `Vector3d` class.
Now you are copying state of `count` field into `v2` object, therefore it starts from 3 not from 0.

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
class Vector3d {
    double x, y, z;
    mutable int count = 0;
public:
    Vector3d(double x, double y, double z);
    Vector3d(const Vector3d&);
    Vector3d& operator=(const Vector3d&);
    Vector3d(Vector3d&&) = delete;
    Vector3d& operator=(Vector3d&&) = delete;
    void Print() const;
    int GetCount() const;
};
Vector3d::Vector3d(double x, double y, double z) {
    Vector3d::x = x;
    Vector3d::y = y;
    Vector3d::z = z;
}
Vector3d::Vector3d(const Vector3d& that)
: Vector3d(that.x, that.y, that.z)
{
}
Vector3d& Vector3d::operator=(const Vector3d& that)
{
    x = that.x;
    y = that.y;
    z = that.z;
    return *this;
}

void Vector3d::Print() const {
    count++;
    std::cout << "{" << x << "," << y << "," << z << "}";
}

int Vector3d::GetCount() const {
    return count;
}

int main() {
    Vector3d v1(1, 2, 3);
    v1.Print();v1.Print();v1.Print();
    Vector3d v2(v1);
    v2.Print();v2.Print();
    std::cout << v2.GetCount();
    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE:
Someone mentioned that explicitly deleted move ctor and operator is not ok, I understand that, but for me it is not clear should we `move` counter to other instance or not. Therefore here possible implementation:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

class Vector3d {
    double x, y, z;
    mutable int count = 0;
public:
    Vector3d(double x, double y, double z);
    Vector3d(const Vector3d&);
    Vector3d(Vector3d&&);
    Vector3d& operator=(Vector3d);
    void Print() const;
    int GetCount() const;

private:
    void swap(Vector3d&);
};
Vector3d::Vector3d(double x, double y, double z) {
    Vector3d::x = x;
    Vector3d::y = y;
    Vector3d::z = z;
}
Vector3d::Vector3d(const Vector3d& that)
        : Vector3d(that.x, that.y, that.z)
{
}
Vector3d::Vector3d(Vector3d&& that)
: Vector3d(that.x, that.y, that.z)
{
    count = that.count;
}
Vector3d& Vector3d::operator=(Vector3d that)
{
    swap(that);
    return *this;
}

void Vector3d::swap(Vector3d& that)
{
    std::swap(x, that.x);
    std::swap(y, that.y);
    std::swap(z, that.z);
    std::swap(count, that.count);
}

void Vector3d::Print() const {
    count++;
    std::cout << "{" << x << "," << y << "," << z << "}";
}

int Vector3d::GetCount() const {
    return count;
}

int main() {
    Vector3d v1(1, 2, 3);
    v1.Print();v1.Print();v1.Print();
    Vector3d v2 = std::move(v1);
    v2.Print();v2.Print();
    std::cout << v2.GetCount();
    return 0;
}
```

But these more for commenters than for question author.

Comment: could you post code example of that solution?

Comment: sure, here we go.

Comment: You may want to `default` rather than `delete` the move special member functions. There may be cases where you want to transfer ownership of an object without having to reset the counter.

Comment: The explicitly `=delete` on the move-ctor and move-assign is unnecessary, as they won't be synthesized if the copy-ctor and copy-assign are provided.  When explicitly `=delete` they are eligible for matching and if best-match or ambiguous will trip the compiler. Which may-or-may-not be what is intended.  (I wish there was a way to explicitly write in code "intentionally not generating this", and not by using a comment.)

Comment: thanks, but we haven't learned changing operators yet. Is there any way to do that with the following knowledge: - Constructors, The role of parameters in constructors, Creating nameless (anonymous) temporary objects using constructors, Copying constructor, Aggregate initialization, Automatic type conversion via constructors, Direct and copying initialization, Creating arrays and vectors whose elements are class instances, Arrays and vectors whose elements pointers to class instances, Constructor initialization lists, Pointers and references as class attributes.

Comment: @EduardRakhmankulov I am against putting "business rules" in basic copy and assignment operations, i.e you are not really making copies at all, but fake copies.  Doing things this way, you open yourself up for some of the most difficult errors (if you don't count multithreaded programs) to debug in C++.  The job of the copy constructor and assignment should be one and one only -- make copies, even if what you want is a subset of the members (which again, is bad anyway).  The one exception to this is if you are creating a true reference counted class (for example, `std::shared_ptr` equivalent)

Comment: This is too much advanced for my current knowledge. Task says this: `the answer to how to do it lies in elements introduced in Lecture 10`. Could you have look at the lecture https://easyupload.io/ub8fhs Is there any way to do this with the knowledge presented in lecture?

Comment: The other issue of putting in side-effects in the basic copy operations is that  a compiler is free (and in specific cases, mandated) to optimize away the copies.  So you now have a program that may run differently depending on compiler flags, compiler, and even version of the compiler.  Try to debug that when your "debug" build runs differently than your "release" build.

Comment: An example of what Paul's talking about. Say you have a `std::vector` of these objects. `std::vector` does a LOT of copying and moving as it resizes. You'll find the counters of the objects in the `vector` will keep getting reset.

Comment: Yes, you should write the copy and assignment operations as if you never know *when* they will be called, just know that they *will* be called at some point by either you explicitly, or the compiler implicitly.  Once you have that engrained in your mind, then you approach writing the overloads of these operations much more carefully (meaning you strive to make *real* copies, not half or partial copies).

Comment: @cpp_mountain -- We don't know what is in "Lecture 10".  If what is in "Lecture 10" means to use the basic copy operations to complete the task, then that lecture is giving horrible advice.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have attached lecture here easyupload.io/ub8fhs

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie If you want thread-safe implementation you can't use `int count` then you should use std::atomic<int> which isn't copyable, so implementation would be essentially the same. I didn't want to make things complicated therefore I didn't mention possible races, which already exists in original post.

Comment: @user4581301 for me is not clear which move-semantics we want for this class, should move-ctor retain count or reset it, thats why I deleted them according rule of 5.

Comment: @EduardRakhmankulov No, my mention of MT programming was only used to illustrate the difficulty of fixing bugs in C++ programs.  Making copy constructors and assignment operators do things other than assigning and copying *is* one of the hardest bugs to find (and to fix once you figure out the issue is with the funky copy and assignment operators, since the odd behavior may be intertwined with the logic of the program).

Comment: @EdRakhmankulov thank you very much, but this is too much advanced for my level. Could you scroll through my lecture to see what is supposed to be done?

Comment: @EdRakhmankulov for the first code, the only two functions we need are `Vector3d(double x, double y, double z);` and `Vector3d(const Vector3d &);` the rest of functions are useless in the context of this task

Comment: @EdRakhmankulov also, your second code doesn't give correct output

Comment: @cpp_mountain Please, call these functions constructors. I would say that other functions are not useless no matter of the context. "Rule of Five" wikipedia article describes exact reasons why you should do so in C++ and what exceptions are.

Comment: @cpp_mountain I don't see where problem is, could you give me output you are getting and expected one?

Comment: right output is 2, and the second code gives output of 5...

Comment: @cpp_mountain you didn't give me full output. I am getting `{1,2,3}{1,2,3}{1,2,3}{1,2,3}{1,2,3}2` see there https://godbolt.org/z/15qEKeoda